# Is there a way to prevent or recover from ListViewItems becoming MS.Internal.NamedObject

Tags: c#, wpf

I have a UserControl that is a ListView with a Canvas as the ItemsPanel. The ItemsSource of the ListView is bound to a CollectionViewSource with it's Source property bound to an ObservableCollection< DeviceItem >. DeviceItem is a custom class that, among other things, holds the X/Y coordinates of the ListViewItem/DeviceItem which gets serialized when the user wants to save their work. On PreviewMouseDown and PreviewTouchDown I check the ListViewItem that's being clicked/touched to make sure that the content of the ListViewItem is a DeviceItem so that as the user moved it around the screen the software can updates the coordinates on the DeviceItem. This works 99% of the time but I run into a problem (sometimes) after the user removes items from the collection and then adds new items. After removing/adding, when the user clicks/touches the ListViewItem it's Content is typeof MS.Internal.NamedObject and in that case I can't act on the item. I'm sure it's worth mentioning that the user is adding/removing from a separate control in another window that is bound to the same collection in our data model (ObservableCollection< DeviceItem >).

Currently the user has to close and reopen the software when this happens. I'm trying to find a way to recover without restarting the software.

```
<UserControl.Resources>
    <Style x:Key="CanvasStyle" TargetType="{x:Type Canvas}">
        <EventSetter Event="Loaded" Handler="Canvas_Loaded"/>
    </Style>
    <CollectionViewSource Source="{Binding DiagramCollection}" x:Key="radioPacksDataView" />
</UserControl.Resources>
<Grid>
    <ListView Name="listBoxDevices"
              Background="Transparent"
              BorderThickness="0"
              Stylus.IsPressAndHoldEnabled ="False"
              ItemsSource="{Binding Source={StaticResource radioPacksDataView}}"
              PreviewMouseMove="ListBox_PreviewMouseMove"
              PreviewMouseDown="ListBox_PreviewMouseDown"
              PreviewMouseUp="ListBox_PreviewMouseUp"
              PreviewTouchDown="ListBox_PreviewTouchDown"
              PreviewTouchMove="ListBox_PreviewTouchMove"
              PreviewTouchUp="ListBox_PreviewTouchUp"
              SnapsToDevicePixels="True"                  
              IsHitTestVisible="{Binding AccessRights, ConverterParameter=Unlocked, Converter={StaticResource enumBooleanConverter}, Source={x:Static appData:Globals.CurrentUser}}"
              VirtualizingPanel.IsVirtualizing="False"
              IsSynchronizedWithCurrentItem="False">
        <ListView.Style>
            <Style>
                <Setter Property="ItemsControl.ItemsPanel">
                    <Setter.Value>
                        <ItemsPanelTemplate>
                            <Canvas Style="{DynamicResource CanvasStyle}"/>
                        </ItemsPanelTemplate>
                    </Setter.Value>
                </Setter>
                <Style.Triggers>
                    <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding ElementName=window, Path=IconStyle}" Value="0">
                        <Setter Property="ListView.ItemContainerStyle" Value="{DynamicResource MultiDeviceItemContainerStyle}" />
                    </DataTrigger>
                    <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding ElementName=window, Path=IconStyle}" Value="1">
                        <Setter Property="ListView.ItemContainerStyle" Value="{DynamicResource MultiDeviceItemContainerStyleV2}" />
                    </DataTrigger>
                </Style.Triggers>
            </Style>
        </ListView.Style>
        <ListView.LayoutTransform>
            <ScaleTransform CenterX="0"
                            CenterY="0"
                            ScaleX="{Binding ZoomScale}"
                            ScaleY="{Binding ZoomScale}"/>
        </ListView.LayoutTransform>
    </ListView>
</Grid>
```

And then in code behind

```
private void ListBox_PreviewMouseDown(object sender, MouseEventArgs e)
{
    if (m_selectedListViewItem == null)
    {
        m_selectedListViewItem = ItemsControl.ContainerFromElement((ListBox)sender, e.OriginalSource as DependencyObject) as ListViewItem;
        //this is the section that fails after removing/adding items, object is typeof(MS.Internal.NamedObject)
        if (m_selectedListViewItem.Content.GetType().IsSubclassOf(typeof(DeviceItem))) 
        {
            m_selectedDeviceItem = m_selectedListViewItem.Content as DeviceItem;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Why aren't you binding SelectedItem?

Comment: I need to get the location of the mouse/touch on the icon so I have the offset before the user starts moving it around. That way the cursor stays in the same location on the icon as they move it. I do that in the PreviewMouseDown event. The problem with using PreviewMouseDown is that it seems to keep the mouse/touch event from selecting the item, even if I set e.Handled = false. That's why I'm using the ListViewItem content to get the DeviceItem instead of binding to SelectedItem.

Comment: Have you tried handling mouse events on ListViewItem? You'd set them up via EventSetters in ListView.ItemContainerStyle.